# PageNumberPagination in django via custom queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

**Scenario** : I am using django rest framework and I want to create an API to list products using `Pagination`.

**Problem:** I have a dictionary coming through a defined method (which shows products for a filtered category) and now I want to pass this dictionary to queryset. Is it feasible?

```
class PageNumberSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    ordering = '-created_at'

class ProductList(ListAPIView):

    queryset = getCategoryProduct()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberSetPagination
```

In settings.py:

```
        REST_FRAMEWORK = {
            'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
            'PAGE_SIZE': 100
        }
```